Un producto en varias categorias php y mysql
Hola tengo el siguiente problema, tengo una tabla Categorias y una tabla Productos
en categoria tengo:
id - Categoria
En producto tengo
id - id_categoria
Cuando voy a la consulta funciona perfecto. me muestra el producto que representa a la categoria.
<?php
            $query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT p.*, c.id AS id_cat, c.categoria FROM productos p INNER JOIN categorias c ON c.id = p.id_categoria WHERE activo=1 ORDER BY nombre ASC");
            $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);
            if ($result > 0) {
                while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { ?>

Todo bien hasta aqui... pero ahora resulta que necesito colocar un mismo producto en 3 diferentes categorias iguales en la opción producto necesito crear tres tablas mas id_categoria2 id_categoria3 para que cuando haga la consulta si la id_categoria2 y la id_categoria3 tienen un valor también me los muestre en dicha categoría.
Pero no se como ordenarlo en la consulta es decir en el codigo que coloque anteriormente.

No tienes que crear tres tablas, tienes un error de concepto. Debes crear una relación muchos a muchos entre la tabla producto y la tabla categoría.

Lo que @Francisco te comenta es que crees una nueva tabla intermedia, entre productos y categorias en la que registrarás las categorías a las que pertenece cada producto, en una fila por cada vínculo.
Efectivamente, en el modelo ER, a esa tabla intermedia se le llama relación y se representa mediante un rombo que, al pasar al modelo relacional, se termina por transformar en una tabla. El problema es que como a las claves ajenas o FK también las llaman relaciones, ahí es donde aparecen las confusiones. Además, las relaciones de uno a muchos se pueden simplificar, eliminando esa tabla intermedia y obteniendo un resultado como el que planteas. He ahí tu error de concepto.
A esa tabla de relación hay quien la llama pivote, que no tiene nada que ver con pivotar una tabla, producto_has_categoria, tabla de join y creo que he visto de más formas. En el modelo ER, la llamamos con un verbo, por ejemplo categorizan, a diferencia de las entidades, a las que identificamos con nombres: productos, categorías, ...
Y, para terminar, elimina el campo id_categoria de la tabla productos, pásalo a esta tabla intermedia categorizan junto al id_categoria.
Al realizar la consulta, haces un JOIN más para tener en cuenta las 3 tablas.
Con eso ya tendrías todo, déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios o indica si necesitas ayuda con la implementación.
